Why does my numpy convolution appear off-centred?
The first part of this post is now not necessary for my question, please see the edit.
I'm trying to convolve two probability maps in Python with numpy.convolve, and decided to use mode='same' so that I could plot the convolution against the original distributions. However, my convolution doesn't seem to be in the correct place, as I would expect its peak to lie between distributions A and B (see figure), or at the very least at a higher value of x than it is now. When I try using mode='full', the convolution occurs in a different place on the x-axis, but still does not occur where I would expect it. The location of the convolution in relation to the original arrays is very important to what I'm doing, so needs to occur between the other two distributions (provided by understanding of maths is right). I don't know why this isn't happening, so does anyone know how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
A plot of probability distributions A and B, and their convolution with mode='same'
A plot of the convolution of A and B with mode='full'
This is the code I'm using (my two input arrays are very long so I've left them out can I can probably find a way to supply them if it would help):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=np.arange(len(GRB_240612A))
x2=np.arange(len(GRB_240612B))
if len(x1)==len(x2):
  x=x1

convolution=np.convolve(GRB_240612A, GRB_240612B, mode='same')

plt.plot(x, GRB_240612A, label='A')
plt.plot(x, GRB_240612B, label='B')
plt.plot(x, convolution, label='Convolution of A and B')

plt.legend()
plt.xlim(0)
plt.ylim(0)
plt.show()

EDIT: I have tried using more reasonable toy arrays at Luca's suggestion and have encountered the same problem. The convolution with mode='same' does not appear where I expect, but the one with mode='full' does. Unfortunately, the graphing module I need to use to represent the data (healpy) only accepts arrays of certain lengths, so I need the convolution with mode'same'.
The graph of this can be seen here: Graph of the toy arrays and two types of numpy convolutions.
My toy code is as follows:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu1=2
sigma1=1
mu2=1
sigma2=0.5
x=np.linspace(-7, 7, num=1000)

p = np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu1) / sigma1)**2) / (sigma1 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
p /=np.sum(p)
q = np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu2) / sigma2)**2) / (sigma2 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
q /=np.sum(q)

c=np.convolve(p, q, mode='full')
c2=np.convolve(p, q, mode='same')

plt.plot(x, p, label='p')
plt.plot(x, q, label='q')
plt.plot(np.linspace(-7, 7, num=len(c)), c, label='Convolution of p and q mode=\'full\'')
plt.plot(x, c2, label='Convolution of p and q with mode=\'same\'')
plt.legend()

In case you want to access the original data, they can be found with the links below. Please be aware that to read them, you will need a tool like healpy which requires a Unix operating system or use of Google's Colabs.
Array A is at: https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/fermi/data/gbm/triggers/2024/bn240612503/quicklook/glg_healpix_all_bn240612503.fit
Array B is at: https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/fermi/data/gbm/triggers/2024/bn240612511/quicklook/glg_healpix_all_bn240612511.fit

You should try to reproduce the issue on two toy arrays of reasonable dimension. If you observe the same issue, edit the question with the data to have a MWE. If not, then the problem is likely related to your data and you should edit the question to include it.

@Luca I've done as you've suggested, thank you for your advice!

@Jacob Where would you expect the result of mode "same" to have its peak? Think of it this way: if you regard p as your function being convolved and q as your convolution kernel, then you should notice that your convolution kernel isn't centered, but shifted by 1 (mu2=1). So, your convolution result should be a blurred, shifted-by-1 version of p. And that's exactly what happens: the peak of the result (red curve) is "blurred" (lower, but spread out) and "shifted" (peak is around 3 rather than around 2).

In fact, it is the way you plot the result of mode "full" that is misleading: You simply assume that the result (green curve) covers the same interval (-7, 7) but with higher sampling rate (num(len(c)), which is 1999, rather than 1000). This, however is not correct. So what I want to say is: In my opinion, the result of mode "same" is correct, it is your expectations that need to be reconsidered.

@simon Ah I did not realise that that assumption was incorrect. I'm using p and q for proxies of probability maps (probability mass functions?) of correlated events which occurred on a sphere (the sky).  Physically, the source of these events has to lie between them and I had believed the convolution would produce a probability distribution of where the source could be (assuming they have the same source). As a convolution is a method to 'sum' probability distributions, why would the resultant distribution occur away from the inputs?

@JacobAyre I am afraid, I am not the one that can help you in this case. I just tried to provide the "technical perspective". As to your actual underlying problem: this might be a problem of misconception (maybe the convolution of probability maps, in principle, doesn't do what you expect) or a problem of modeling (maybe the convolution of probability maps in your particular problem just needs to be set up a bit differently). I hope you will get some more input from someone else. In any case: all the best!

@simon Yeah it probably is a lack of understanding combined with the particulars of the problems, I am very new to convolutions. Thank you for your help so far though!
